# How to add a caption to a resized table with scalebox in xtable?

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

I'm working on a R Markdown document. I've got a dataframe of this kind:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xtable)

df <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = 1:10, c = 1:10, d = 1:10, e = 1:10, f =1:10,
g = 1:10, h = 1:10, i = 1:10)
```

I'm using the xtable package to create display a table. Since the table is too wide, I scale the table with the scalebox parameter

```
xt <- xtable(df, caption = "Table 1")
print(xt, type = "latex", comment = FALSE,floating = F, 
include.rownames = F, scalebox = 0.50)
```

However, the caption is not displayed on the document. What can I do?

Comment: Thanks. It worked by adding the parameter `table.placement = "!h"` & `floating = TRUE`

Comment: It is generally considered bad practice to use `h` on its own (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132106/difference-between-h-and-h-in-float-position)). You may also choose `table.placement = "H"` if you are trying to strictly hold the float in position.

Comment: Thanks. It worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not limited to using `xtable`, I would recommend making the switch to `knitr::kable` and `kableExtra`.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = 1:10, c = 1:10, d = 1:10, e = 1:10, f =1:10,
g = 1:10, h = 1:10, i = 1:10)
```

```{r table, results='asis'}
df %>%
  kable("latex", caption = "Table 1", booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```
````

Produces...

[image]

In addition, there is an equivalent `scale_down` option available to `latex_options`. However, as noted in the [vignette](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) it will fit to page width and therefore also scale up if the table is not sufficiently wide.

[image]